# Reduce Spark Tasks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a problem where Spark is spinning up almost 2,000 executors and saving the data takes a very long time. All the transformations have already been completed.

Displaying the dataframe before writing completes in a reasonable timeframe but writing the file takes a very long time.

[Spark write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jb63.png)
[dag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1SuP.png)

I tried changing number of executors, cluster size, repartition, coalesce. It seems like the problem of writing many small files. However, df.coalesce(1).write. takes a very long time too.

Is there something in the Dag to look for?

Comment: Sjoe code pls. Executors or Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You only have 16 executors, you do have ~2000 tasks for those executors to complete.  You should look to see if you have [Adaptive Query Enabled](https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/aqe.html#enable-and-disable-adaptive-query-execution).

> ```
> spark.databricks.optimizer.adaptive.enabled
>
> Type: Boolean
> ```

[Non Databricks version](https://spark.conf.set(%22spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled%22,true)):

> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled",true)

This will automagically reduce the number of files written if it detects that they're small enough to merge(requires configuration) or help you with Skew(requires configuration) if that's a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - it still resulted in 1808 tasks. No difference in setting AQE.

Comment: Well that might be an issue with your structure of JSON and your partition choices.  You may have to examine how you can restucture your output to use less partitions if thats your choice.